# Minitab question about binomial probabilities

Tags: self-study, binomial-distribution, minitab

[image]

What I have tried:
My first instinct was to go to Calc>Binomial distributions> Binomial to get the graph of it.

[image]

---

***2 questions:***

1. What does the question mean it needs values less than 21? Should the question be renamed to to the percentage of values less than 21?  I think it means p(x<21).
2. What is the purpose of the code that says
   *"Random 25 c1;
   binomial 25 0.8"*?

Am I supposed to be input this code somewhere?

Comment: Please add the `[self-study]` tag & read its 
[wiki](http://stats.stackexchange.com/tags/self-study/info).

Comment: It's not sufficient to simply add the tag and read the wiki. You must also modify your question to follow the guidelines on asking such questions. In particular, you'll need to clearly identify what you've done to solve the problem yourself, and indicate the specific help you need at the point you struck difficulty.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you enter the commands

```
Random 25 c1;
binomial 25 0.8.
```

into Minitab either

1. in the Command Line Editor (on the Edit menu or Ctrl-L) or
2. at the MTB > prompt in the session window (if commands are enabled on the
   Editor menu)

you will end up with 25 values in C1.

To accomplish the same from menus use Calc > Random Data > Binomial... and enter

- Number of rows of data = 25
- Store in column(s) = C1
- Number of trials = 25
- Event probability = 0.8

The question "How many of your values are less than 21?" is now just a matter of counting. 
I can't tell you the answer because the values are random. Clearly it has to be integer, expect something around 14.

Comment: So I'm assuming whoever is marking this will have a range of answers to choose from? Since the values are random.